# Why can't I start a second bounty on a question offering less rep than the first bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I added a bounty for 400r to this question last week and awarded it a few days ago:

[Methods for improving color choice and combinations?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50742/methods-for-improving-color-choice-and-combinations)

Today I was going to start another bounty to reward another answer. However, upon doing so I can only create a bounty for *more* than my first bounty. So, the only option I'm presented is 500r.

[image]

Why can't I add a 50r or 100r bounty now?

Is it just to prevent too much rep sharing?
<sub>(Which wouldn't really make sense since 500 > 100 :) )</sub>

Comment: Interesting, did not know about this one...

Comment: I did check other questions and all rep values are present there. It's only this question, with a previous bounty from me, that is showing the restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done to prevent (potential) abuse. Unfortunately, you're not given the benefit of the doubt in this case and forced to increase your offer. [Here's the explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275/216955) on MSE:

> As noted by Robert, this has come up recently. Posting a bounty is a
>   perfectly reasonably thing, a *good* thing (with badges too!).
>   However, when applied repeatedly to a question it does start to
>   represent abuse.
>
> To help minimise this, but while leaving open the option of offering a
>   subsequent bounty when you *really, really* are looking for another
>   option we will be implementing a change here, where subsequent
>   bounties have a higher minimum offering. This means you can't place 6
>   "cheap" bounties of 50 rep, to keep your answer on the bounty board to
>   get lots of pass-by upvotes, as subsequent bounties
>   **probably<sup>1</sup> will not** cover your "spend".
>
> We now double the minimum "spend" for successive bounties *on the same
>   question by the same user.* So if you started at 50: your next bounty
>   on that question has a minimum of 100, the next 200, the next 400, the
>   next (max).
>
> Another related change [has been mentioned by Sam
>   Saffron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/134300):
>
> > - If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is **100**
>
> <sub>1=Unless of course your answer is super-awesome, but if it is
>   super-awesome it'll probably already be doing the rounds *for free*
>   (insert obvious regex/html jape here).</sub>

Comment: Okay, that make sense... and may change the initial value of bounties I offer :) My desire wasn't to call attention or keep the question afloat, but I can see how that could be abused.